# Configure newline characters while reading file

Tags: rust

I am new to rust programming and trying to read a file line by line. It seems as it removes newline characters in the end and returns only the text.
I am reading a metadata file where it has \n as well as \r\n.
File sample is below where I have added \n and \r\n explicitly.

```
TAG 0\n
15:\n
32348SIPpTag091\n

SDP from 0 after offer
215:
v=0\r\n
o=user1 53655765 2353687637 IN IP4 172.31.8.95\r\n
s=-\r\n
c=IN IP4 172.31.8.95\r\n
t=0 0\r\n
m=audio 34218 RTP/AVP 8\r\n
c=IN IP4 172.31.8.95\r\n
a=direction:both\r\n
a=label:a_leg\r\n
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\n
a=sendonly\r\n
a=rtcp:34219\r\n
```

I am capturing this information in a map, where `TAG 0` is my key and `32348SIPpTag091` is the value and this line `15:` gives me the length of value. Based on this length I am figuring out whether I have received the value or not.
But with my below code I am losing \r along with \n and because of that the length is not matching with the content.
Is there a way in rust where I can configure to only look for \n for newline or not to remove those characters from the line.
Here is my code

```
fn read_meta(path: &str) -> MetaInfo {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let mut idx: String = String::from("");
    let mut data: String = String::from("");
    let mut dlen: i32 = -1;

    println!("reading from {}", path);
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if idx.is_empty() {
            if line.len() <= 1 {
                continue;
            }
            idx = String::from(line.trim_end_matches("\n"));
        } else if dlen == -1 {
            let c = String::from(line.trim_end_matches("\n").trim_end_matches(":"));
            dlen = c.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        } else {
            data = data + &line;
            if data.len() as i32 >= dlen {
                let diff = (data.len() as i32 - dlen) * -1;
                if diff < 0 {
                    let val = data.chars().take(dlen as usize).collect();
                    map.insert(idx.to_string(), val);
                } else {
                    map.insert(idx.to_string(), data);
                }
                idx = String::from("");
                dlen = -1;
                data = String::from("");
            }
        }
    }
    let meta_info = MetaInfo {
        index: String::from(map.get("PARENT").unwrap()),
        is_complete: map.contains_key("PARENT") && map.contains_key("SDP from 1 after answer")
    };
    return meta_info;

}
```

Comment: If the format you're parsing has a field of a known size `n` that starts at a known point, you should probably `read_exact(&mut buf)` (for a buffer of size `n`) or `take(n).read_to_string(&mut buf)` and then call `buf.lines()` if you need to also split the payload.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed, the `lines` utility will strip out ending newlines (CR LF or LF alone) for convenience. This is not configurable

If you do not want this behaviour, you can use the lower-level [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line): it will read a line and put it in the buffer you provided *including* the EOL content, whether it's a lone LF or CR LF. It's not an iterable though so you'll have to process it by hand e.g.:

```rust
let mut buf = String::new();
while let Ok(n) = reader.read_line(&mut buf) {
    if n == 0 { break; } // eof

    // do stuff with `buf` string here

    buf.clear(); // otherwise the data will accumulate in your buffer
}
```

[playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0b8c8cd5a85143ee8a74fa858f8334e)